# django unable to save req body to sqlitedb

Tags: python, django, model

I have a nitpicky problem with my Django rest api, I'm using postman to POST in some basic information as raw json then make an instance of the model 'Planet' then store it in the sqlite db that comes with django as standard,

I'm getting a 200 response but it is failing the try block for some weird reason?, I have tried changing the param values and also the model data types but it doesn't seem to fix it, there are no errors server side either hoping someone can point out my logic error here :)

Model class

```
class Planet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    temp = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hrs = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mass = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    diameter = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    circumference = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

```
def add_planet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload = json.loads(request.body)
        planet_name = payload['name']
        avg_temp = payload['temp']
        day_hrs = payload['hrs']
        planet_mass = payload['mass']
        planet_diameter = payload['diameter']
        planet_circumference = payload['circumference']


        //data prints out correctly here
        print(planet_name,avg_temp,day_hrs,planet_mass,planet_diameter,planet_circumference) 

        planet = Planet(name=planet_name,temp=avg_temp,hrs=day_hrs,mass=planet_mass, diameter=planet_diameter, circumference=planet_circumference)

        try:
            planet.save()
            response = json.dumps([{ 'Success': 'Planet added successfully!'}])
        except:
            response = json.dumps([{ 'Error': 'Planet could not be added!'}])
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='text/json')
```

here is my json body being sent in postman, I'm using POST and raw json as my option as I don't have a form or a UI here to funnel the data

```
{
    "name": "henry",
    "temp": "40",
    "hrs": "34",
    "mass":"134000",
    "diameter": "8000",
    "circumference":"24000" 
}
```

any help is most appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

this recompiled my modules correctly and added the correct corresponding table which was not there at the creation of my app even after running the migrate command on its own